# C Program prints 0.00000 everytime but returns correct answer

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I have some pretty simple code that I'm having issues with. This program simply just calculates someone's weight in kilograms and displays it. However, every time I run, the printed answer comes back as 0.00000 but returns the correct answer. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    float w;
    float const wc=0.454;

    printf("Enter your weight in pounds ");
    scanf("%f", &w); 

    float wk = w * wc;

    printf("Your weight in kilograms is: %f", &wk);

    return(wk);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick FYI: The return code from the `main` function is the success/fail indicator of the program. Generally speaking zero is considered success and a small positive number a failure.

Comment: Compiler warnings. Enable them and read them.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to pass the address of a variable as the argument to format specifier to print the value. You need to change

```
 printf("Your weight in kilograms is: %f", &wk);
```

to

```
 printf("Your weight in kilograms is: %f", wk);
```

That said,

1. Always check the return value of `scanf()`. Without that, in case `scanf("%f", &w);` fails, you'll be invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you'll end up using an unitialized local variable `float wk = w * wc;` in `float wk = w * wc;`.
2. Please don't make `return` look like a function. Try to stick to `return wk;`.

Comment: and the way to check the return value is... (if(scanf(things) != numOfThingsScaned){ just stop everything.} )